# How would I keep a chat session open with strophe while still allowing users to navigate to other pages?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, strophe

I'm sorry if that question seems vague but here's what I have.

On the side of my webpage I have a chat script that performs the following functions each and every time the page is called up.

1. Connects to my BOSH server
2. Pulls data according to who is logged in
3. Displays the user's roster on the sidebar

I'm trying to save bandwidth (also prevent the user from being logged in/logged out each time they move pages) by keeping the chat window open on the side and using a frame concept to load the other data, similar to how Facebook does things.

I'm aware of

```
history.pushState({},"New Title Goes Here","http://facebook.com/Something");
```

but I know there must be something more to it. Just a little lost on where to start looking. AJAX I know if going to play a big part of it, but I don't like to rely solely on javascript all the time.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

sorry if this is a little late but you can use [Strophe's attach function](http://strophe.im/strophejs/doc/1.0.2/files2/strophe-js.html#Strophe.Connection.attach) so that your BOSH session will not be lost in between page reloads.

What you need to do is first, *connect and authenticate to your XMPP server* then *save the JID, RID and SID* where it wont be lost when your page refreshes. In your session or a cookie for example.

```
var conn = new Strophe.Connection('your_bosh_url');
conn.attach(your_jid, your_sid, your_rid, function(status){
  if(status === Strophe.Status.ATTACHED){
  *and so on ...*
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a content div and a chat div. My website uses AJAX to just be nice, so I have a nav div and a content div, and I load things with jQuery. Take a look at my site: http://derek.genevievehoward.com/ and this JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/howderek/tNVd8/

For some reason JSFiddle doesn't like the AJAX, but my website uses the same javascript, so I can assure you it's accurate.